# Match by Dates-total match and mismatch

Tags: sql, function, join

I am trying to lookup ID values from two tables  which have dates ..I am trying to match  value by date....Can you please help me .In table I have added the column matching just for reference...So the result that I am looking for is count of values that match by date with table 2, the values that match and the count of values,values  that dont match by date with table 2

Also I want to calculate the percentage of values that match by date to the total values in that date (distinct values) ,the percentage of values that do not match by date to the total values in that date (distinct values)

Table 1

```
Date    ID  Matching
1-Sep   103 103
1-Sep   102 102
1-Sep   101 NA
4-Sep   105 105
4-Sep   106 106
5-Sep   101 NA
5-Sep   104 NA
5-Sep   106 NA
5-Sep   199 199
5-Sep   200 200
```

table 2

```
Date    ID
1-Sep   102
1-Sep   103
4-Sep   105
4-Sep   106
5-Sep   199
5-Sep   200
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that you want.  A tag for a specific database is also helpful.

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve] & hits googling 'stackexchange homework'.

Comment: Sure Gordon!,,Will make sure to ask questions with utmost clarity going forward...My Apologies!..Can you please allow me to ask more questions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get `matching` with an outer join:

```
select t1.id, t1.date, t2.id
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.date = t2.date and t1.id = t2.id;
```

You can get the percent matching by doing:

```
select count(t2.id) * 1.0 / count(*)
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.date = t2.date and t1.id = t2.id;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon!..Really appreciate your help